# Pass from Textbox to VM > Services

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="308,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text = "{Binding Login, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
    UserService userService = new UserService();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = userViewModel;
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        userService.CheckUserExist();

    }
```

**Model:**

```
public string Login { get; set; }
```

**ViewModel:**

public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _login;

```
public string Login
{
    get { return _login; }
    set
    {
        _login = value;
        OnPropertyChange("Login");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

}

**Service:**

```
public string Login { get; set; }

        public void CheckUserExist()
        {
            using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, Login);
                if (user == null)
                { UserMessageText = "xx"; }
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Why Login in method CheckUserExist() is always null when i start it?
I tried with UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus and RaisePropertyChanged();
From method data are correctly sent to VM i View.

Comment: How did you pass `Login` from VM to model and service?

Comment: Put service inside of the ViewModel->create Command in the ViewModel->call method in service (Use Binding!!!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is always `null` because you never set it. Also when following the *MVVM* pattern, your view is not allowed to have a dependency to the model or the `UserService` to be specific.
It's the responsibility of the view model to pass the value from `UserViewModel.Login` to `UserService.Login`:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this.userViewModel;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Login}"/>
  <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitLoginDataCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**UserViewModel.cs**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  public void SubmitLoginData(object loginData)
  {
    this.userService.CheckUserExist(this.Login);
  }

  public ICommand SubmitLoginDataCommand => new RelayCommand(SubmitLoginData, param => true);
  public string Login { get; set; }  
  private UserService userService { get; set; }
}
```

**UserService.cs**

```
public void CheckUserExist(string login)
{
  using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
  {
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, login);
    if (user == null)
    { 
      this.UserMessageText = "xx"; 
    }
  }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**
Implementation taken from [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
  #region Fields 
  readonly Action<object> _execute;
  readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
  #endregion // Fields 
  #region Constructors 
  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
  {
    if (execute == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
    }

    this._execute = execute; this._canExecute = canExecute;
  }
  #endregion // Constructors 
  #region ICommand Members 
  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return this._canExecute == null ? true : this._canExecute(parameter);
  }
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }
  public void Execute(object parameter) { this._execute(parameter); }
  #endregion // ICommand Members 
}
```

Comment: public ICommand SubmitLoginDataCommand = new RelayCommand(SubmitLoginData, param => true);

cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Huh, I never used Commands :/

Comment: No problem. I posted a `RelayCommand` implementation from Microsoft. Also I had a typo in the definition of the `SubmitLoginDataCommand`: I forgot the '>' as this is supposed to be a read-only property using expression body syntax: `ICommand SubmitLoginDataCommand => new RelayCommand(SubmitLoginData, param => true);`

Comment: I updated the answer. Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Everything works fine, thank you!
I have to read more about ICommand.